# How to use regex to replace text in forwarded email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, vba

I have the following code that I pulled from, niton ([VBA to forwarding emails in Outlook](https://superuser.com/questions/1508890/vba-to-forwarding-emails-in-outlook)).

```
Private Sub objInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

    Dim objMail As MailItem
    Dim objForward As MailItem
    
    Dim beginStr As String
    Dim lenBegin As Long

    beginStr = "Report - Daily Sales"
    lenBegin = Len(beginStr)

    If TypeOf item Is MailItem Then

        Set objMail = item

        'New email where the "beginning is the same"
        If Left(objMail.Subject, lenBegin) = beginStr Then

            Set objForward = objMail.Forward

            'Customize the forward subject, body and recipients'
            With objForward
                .Subject = "Daily Sales Report as of: " + Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")
                .HTMLBody = objForward.HTMLBody
                .Recipients.Add ("Rkartye@freebirds.com")
                .Display    '.Send
            End With

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

It works perfectly and alters the subject but I cannot figure out how to delete text from the body. I will be removing all text and leaving only the pictures if there is a function to do that it would be best, if not is there a good tutorial or example on how to use replace and regex with replace? Decent at VBA in excel but first time using in outlook.

Thanks

Comment: Alternatively you could save the attachments, delete the entire body, then append the pictures to the forwarded body `.InlineShapes.AddPicture strFile, False, True`. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/dd492012(v=office.12) **17.5.4 Inserting pictures**.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are working with objForward.HTMLBody - Here is a regex I've tried on regex101.com:

`(<(img|IMG) [^>]+>)`

Which I tested against the following string

`<HTML><BODY>This is text <img src="http://example.com/path/test.img" /> and then <IMG src="http://example.com/path/test2.img" /></BODY></HTML>`

You could use that to pull out all the matches and then wrap them with a new set of  and  tags.

Hopefully that helps, but I, unfortunately, cannot help with the VBA for the code to set up regex searches - however, here's a link that may provide an example on that front:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65195118/regular-expression-in-excel-vba-to-perform-exact-match

Comment: Thanks for the thought, looked through the HTML code of the email and it is a beast. The email I am forwarding comes from our BI tool, so there is no way I could write a function to only keep the images, I also do not know HTML. Would it be possible to reverse this logic to remove the text I need removed? If so do I need to remove any of the HTML code with the test? For example we have a textbox stating the email was received from outside the company, this is in a red box and has HTML code saying the font, size, color, and box dimensions.

Comment: That is hard to say without seeing a rough sample to see what surrounds the text. Or is the text you are trying to remove predictable - for example you mention the red box, the code around this would always be the same so you could target that for deletion.

VBA has the regex replace function that could help with this